# Reauthenticate user with firebase UI

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI and trying to handle cases where I get:

> This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request".

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

My solution is to check whether a user needs re-authenticating, then sign them out and start the firebase UI sign in flow again. How can I check whether a user needs re-authenticating?

I'm hoping for something like `firebase.auth().currentUser.requiresReauthenication` which contains a boolean.